# iOS - Removing subview causes other views to shift

Tags: ios, subview

I have a weird problem. In my app, I am allowing users to post screenshots to facebook. I remove a few subviews that I don't want in the screenshot, then re-add them later after the screenshot is taken.

My problem is, whenever I remove the UITextView, it dramatically shifts a 2 of my other image views to the left, causing them to go partly off screen.

Another thing to note: I am using a Tab Controller, with 5 views. All the views do the same thing for different TV Characters. They all use the same class. Only 2 of my characters are having this weird shifting issue, yet all the code is the same for all 5 characters. I have also ensured all my outlets are wired up correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have autoresize set on any of the views that are moving? If you set them up in IB, it might be possible they are just moving to fill the void.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution; set all the views I didn't want in the screenshot to hidden, then re-enabled them once the screenshot was captured.